# Getting Null data from google adwords api

Tags: asp.net, google-ads-api

I want to fetch location details for all the ads from google adwords but I am getting null entries.I am not able to get any data from adwords api .Help me in That as according to my knowledge there is not problem with my code and I am not able to find any solution for that.My code that I have tried is written below.

```
 public void GetLocationAds()
            {

                AdWordsUser user = new AdWordsUser();

                {
                    try
                    {
                        int offset = 0;                                        

                        // Create selector.
                        using (CampaignCriterionService campaignCriterionService =
                            (CampaignCriterionService)user.GetService(AdWordsService.v201809.CampaignCriterionService))




                        {
                            Selector selector = new Selector()
                            {
                                fields = new string[]
                             {
                                  CampaignCriterion.Fields.CampaignId,
                                    CampaignCriterion.Fields.CampaignCriterionStatus,
                                     //Location.Fields.LocationName,
                                     //Location.Fields.CriteriaType,
                                     //Location.Fields.ParentLocations,
                                     //LocationCriterion.Fields.CanonicalName,
                                     //LocationCriterion.Fields.CountryCode,
                                  CampaignCriterion.Fields.IsNegative,


                             },
                           //     predicates = new Predicate[]
                           //{

                           //    Predicate.Equals( "CriteriaType","LOCATION"),
                           //},
                                paging = Paging.Default,
                                ordering = new OrderBy[]
                       {
                                OrderBy.Asc(  CampaignCriterion.Fields.CampaignId)


                       }
                            };

                            CampaignCriterionPage page = new CampaignCriterionPage();




                            do
                            {

                                // Get the ad groups.

                                 page = campaignCriterionService.get(selector);

                                // Display the results.
                                if (page != null && page.entries != null)
                                {
                                    int j = selector.paging.startIndex;
                                    foreach (CampaignCriterion campaignCriterion in page.entries)
                                    {
                                        var campaignId = campaignCriterion.campaignId;
                                        bool IsLocation = campaignCriterion.isNegative;
                                        var CampaignCriterionType = campaignCriterion.CampaignCriterionType;

                                    }

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.Write("No campaignCriterion were found.");
                                }

                                selector.paging.IncreaseOffset();

                            }
                            while (selector.paging.startIndex < page.totalNumEntries);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    }

                }
            }
```

Kindly help me in that.